# Action bar do not show

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Action bar works fine in emulator, android phone 4.4 .

But Action bar do not come in android version 4.1

I am confuse for this problem, Please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Menifest file:

```
   <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />



    <permission
          android:name="info.staffmark.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
          android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="info.staffmark.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        >
        <activity
            android:name="info.staffmark.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"

            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

MainActivity:

```
mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        ctx = getApplicationContext();



        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_custom_view_home);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        actionBar.show();
```

This is some code of my app retalted to action bar.

Comment: Can you please be more specific about what have you done and what comes out like sharing at least some portions of relevant Manifests and telling your current SDK version?

Comment: i am using Sdk version is 4.4.w.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will get the job done but you should give it a try

```
final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar().show();
```

**EDIT:** Add this before `setContentView`

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
```

Comment: Argh can't believe I overlooked it. So sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

Finally after searching a lot,

I know my problem, I am using sdk version 4.4.w

Then i change sdk from 4.4.w  to 4.3.

I can see action bar now.....